# an array of strings as a jQuery selector?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of strings that are valid jQuery selectors (i.e. IDs of elements on the page):

```
["#p1", "#p2", "#p3", "#p4", "#p5"]
```

I want to select elements with those IDs into a jQuery array. This is probably elementary, but I can't find anything online. I could have a for-loop which creates a string `"#p1,#p2,#p3,#p4,#p5"` which could then be passed to jQuery as a single selector, but isn't there another way? Isn't there a way to pass an array of strings as a selector?

**EDIT:** Actually, there is [an answer out there already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list/201733).

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Well, there's 'join':

```
["#p1", "#p2", "#p3", "#p4", "#p5"].join(", ")
```

EDIT - Extra info:

It is possible to select an array of elements, problem is here you don't have the elements yet, just the selector strings. Any way you slice it you're gonna have to execute a search like .getElementById or use an actual jQuery select.

Comment: join() is exactly it. Thank you.

Answer (score 14):

Try the [Array.join method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join):

```
var a = ["#p1", "#p2", "#p3", "#p4", "#p5"];
var s = a.join(", ");
//s should now be "#p1, #p2, #p3, ..."
$(s).whateverYouWant();
```

Answer (score 9):

What about `$(foo.join(", "))`?

Answer (score 4):

Use the array.join method to join them together

```
$(theArray.join(','));
```

Comment: Hehe, I knew I'd be too slow on this darn iphone :-)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time anyway!

Answer (score 4):

Going to officially answer your question: with a one-liner:

```
//If this is only one use variable you can use
$(['#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4','#p5'].join(',')).methodToUse();
//if you DO need it as a variable you can
var joined = ['#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4','#p5'].join(',');
$(joined).methodsToUse();
```

If you want them to do something individually there is also .each();

In the example below, each p ids clicks makes any one of them red:

```
var peas = ['#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4','#p5'];
$.each(peas, i => {
    $(peas[i]).click(() => {
        $(peas[i]).css({'color':'red'});
    });
});
```

When you throw 'i' into a function parameter, it finds the values inside the arrays appropriately.  When you do '.each()'  the format looks like this:

```
$.each(array, function(i){
    // any code you wish as long as you have an array selector
    //$(array[i]).whatever function
});
```

An even bigger example.  Say you want to make the P you click on red, but want the other ps return to default color.  Just make a function that removes the selected ID from the array and voila!

```
var peas = ['#p1','#p2','#p3','#p4','#p5'],
    poppy=(v,i)=>peas.toString().replace(`,${v[i]}`,'').replace(`${v[i]},`,'');

(// get each pea index
  $.each(peas,i=>///funciton(i){ code inside}

    (//set up each individual index's functions
      $('.peastock').append(`<p id="p${[i+1]}">I am ${peas[i]}</p>`),
      $(peas[i]).click(()=>(
        $(peas[i]).css({"color":"red","background-color":"rgba(128,0,0,0.1)"}),
        $(poppy(peas,i)).css({'color':'black','background-color':'rgba(255,255,255,0.2)'}))))),

  $('.peastock').append(`
    <div id="ree">ES6 isnt suitable for all of jQuery's usage!</div>
    <div>Since some functions inside of jQuery's methods dont require 'this' or 'return'</div>
    <div>You can learn this by going <a href="https://www.w3schools.com/Js/js_es6.asp">here</a></div>
  `),
  $("*").css({"margin":"0 auto","padding":"1%"}),
  $("* .peastock, .peastock, .peastock *").css({"background-color":"rgba(128,0,0,0.1)"})
);
```

I know someone is bound to want to know about each value array as jquery selectors.  Hope everything goes well!

Source:
[jQuery .each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)
[The fiddle in action (with updates!)](https://jsfiddle.net/NitroXAce/t9ewpnj2/82/)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [join](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp).

```
var arr = ["#p1", "#p2", "#p3", "#p4", "#p5"];
$(arr.join(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
$( ["#p1", "#p2", "#p3", "#p4", "#p5"].toString() );
```

Comment: Many overcomplicated answers, while yours is (just a bit) faster. I'll edit it to fit the scope of jQuery. Nice one!