# jQuery Selector from String Array

Tags: jquery

There's a similar answer here but it's somehow different and doesn't fit my case, I can't just do a `join()`:
[an array of strings as a jQuery selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002073/an-array-of-strings-as-a-jquery-selector)

I have a dynamic array that looks like this,

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

I need to do a Selector string as follows including all these values as a `data-event` attribute as follows:

```
$('li.event[data-event="' + /*every element from the array*/ + '"]');
```

Is there a way to avoid looping?

Comment: What is the value of the `data-event` you're trying to match with?

Comment: Every element of the array `data-event` needs to be included in the Selector string shown. That is my selector. e.g.: `.event[data-event="abc"], .event[data-event="def"], .event[data-event="ghi"]`.

Comment: can you add html element you want to select

Comment: Yeah, it wasn't necessary but I added the LI element I'm selecting so it's clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every element of the array data-event needs to be included in the Selector string shown. That is my selector. e.g.: `.event[data-event="abc"], .event[data-event="def"], .event[data-event="ghi"]`.

In this case you need to build a separate selector for each element and `join()` them together. You can achieve that using `map()`:

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];
var selector = arr.map(function(el) {
  return `.event[data-event="${el}"]`;
}).join(',');

$(selector).addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo { color: #C00; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event" data-event="abc">ABC</div>
<div class="event" data-event="def">DEF</div>
<div class="event" data-event="ghi">GHI</div>
<div class="event" data-event="xyz">XYZ</div>
```

Comment: Just one comment. In IE11 the notation`${el}` doesn't work -- nor does the backtick, ```. I had to change it to  `return '.event[data-event="' + el + '"]'`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution without `.map()`

```js
var arr = ['abc','def','ghi'];

var test = 'li.event[data-event="' + arr.join('"],li.event[data-event="') + '"]';

console.log(test);
```

Answer (score 0):

The goal is to obtain a selector that looks like:

```
.event[data-event="abc"],.event[data-event="def"],.event[data-event="ghi"]
```

You *can* do this with `join` in a slightly different way:

```js
var arr = ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'];

var part1 = '.event[data-event="';
var part2 = '"]';

var sel = part1 + arr.join(part2 + "," + part1) + part2;

console.log(sel);
```