# Are Javascript string arrays automatically separated by commas?

Tags: javascript

After reading [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list) and [this article](http://www.hunlock.com/blogs/Mastering_Javascript_Arrays), I still have this question. Let's say I have the following snippet:

```
var arr = new Array(3);
arr[0] = "Zero";
arr[1] = "One";
arr[2] = "Two";

document.write(arr.join(","));
```

If I replace the `document.write()` line with `document.write(arr);`, are they equivalent? Does the replacement statement automatically join array elements with a comma as the delimiter?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not try it yourself?

Comment: They look equivalent, but I don't know why.

Comment: What do you mean by equivalent? Do you mean do they simply look the same when output to the browser?

Comment: Output looks the same to the browser. But I couldn't figure out why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"But I couldn't figure out why"

This is because everything has a `toString` function as part of its prototype. When you write it out, this function is invoked to get the string representation of whatever it is. For arrays, the default handling is the same as `join`.

```
Array.prototype.toString.apply([1,2,3]) == Array.prototype.join.apply([1,2,3])
> true
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing the array to document.write() will separate them with commas by default.

http://jsfiddle.net/XnW7V/

```
var arr = new Array(3);
arr[0] = "Zero";
arr[1] = "One";
arr[2] = "Two";

document.write(arr); //outputs Zero,One,Two
```

Comment: So it is separated with commas by default?

Comment: The commas are added as part of the formatting.  The array actually does not have commas in it.  If you looked in memory there would be a slot for each of the elements containing the value without commas.  I am guessing the document.write() function has some conditional logic within it that determines what was passed as a param, if it is an array it must join them with commas and spit out the result.

Comment: I meant are the commas added by default for formatting purposes according to the Javascript standard?

Comment: I don't know if the spec states it but clearly that is the functionality of the method.