# convert Javascript array into csv

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, export-to-csv

I have been using this (rather good) tool to make a csv into a javascript array:
http://www.creativyst.com/cgi-bin/Prod/17/eg/csv2js.pl

I was editing the csv and using the array very nicely.  Now it seems that all my csv files are corrupt. All I have is a working javascript array, 300 vars, 8000 lines of code.

What is the best way to recreate a csv from this array?  Is there a nice copy and paste tool online?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See ([Easy way to turn Javascript array into comma-separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list).)

You'll need to use either the `join()` function or `document.write`

Comment: From the way I understand this, it will recreate the 22 csv entries for each var. I have over 300 vars.  Is there a way to not manually do this 300 times?

Comment: Wasnt exactly what I was looking for but I was able to get what I needed done by using it - thanks