# Javascript comma seperated values not working

Tags: jquery

I have a variable A as follows:

```
A = [[a],[b],[c],[d],.....]
```

I need to make this array to comma separated values as:

```
A = a,b,c,d,....
```

What I did is as follows:

```
A = A.replace("[", "");
A = A.replace("]", "");
```

But not working!!

Getting error as `A.replace is not a function`

Comment: Are you having array or string ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easy way to turn Javascript array into comma-separated list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list)

Comment: can you provide [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), that can reproduce your problem?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/):

```
_.flatten(A).join(',')
```

EDIT: underscore in not actually needed (kudos [@Grundy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881286/grundy)):

```
A.join(',')
```

Comment: any lib not needed - `join` is enough

Comment: It is coming from ajax so it is a variable. sorry I mistakenly put it as array!!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var A = [["a"],["b"],["c"],["d"]];
alert(A.toString()); // .join not even needed
```

Comment: `join` return same result as `toString` but you can concatenate not only by comma :-)

Comment: I know: _I need to make this array to comma separated values_

Comment: @mplungjan updated my question. please check buddy!!

Comment: Updated in what way? Does my answer answer your question or is the situation different than you described?

Comment: @Grundy it is String!!  Getting error as replace is not a function

Comment: @NeethuRaj, if this `string` so check that correct write `replace` otherwise check type variable, possibly it not a string :-)

Comment: Sorry buddy I tried alert( typeof A); It is getting Object. It is returning from ajax!!]

Comment: @NeethuRaj, can you provide [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net) that can reproduce your error?

Comment: Can you post an actual example of the JSON and an actual example of what you want it to look like? And again, does my answer address your issue? - lastly, My name is Michel, not Buddy...

Comment: @mplungjan it is interesting, but is some browser `join` can be faster :-) https://jsperf.com/tostring-join

Comment: Interesting. On my browser/platform, toString is faster

Comment: Rarely use ie. Chrome is my current favourite

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88681/discussion-between-grundy-and-mplungjan).