# Selectize.js: add category label to the selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, selectize.js

[selectize.js](https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js)

It is possible to add a non selectable category (label) to the input selection?

[image]

The problem is, that I have a big list of inputs and it would be great to add categories (labels) to the selection. Like this:

```
Category 1
---Item1
---Item2
---Item3
---Item4
Category 2
---Item5
---Item6
---Item7
---Item8
...etc
```

Comment: Selectize.js, as it is, only returns the a list with tags selected (no matter the category they are in). You mean you want it to return the list of selected tags divided by category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable both tag creation and option groups. It seems to work [here](http://jsfiddle.net/angelalb/eoj9p29g/).

Use a `select` element, with `optgroup` for categories:

```
<select id="select-gear" class="demo-default" multiple placeholder="Select gear...">
    <option value="">Select gear...</option>
    <optgroup label="Climbing">
        <option value="pitons">Pitons</option>
        <option value="sling">Sling</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Skiing">
        <option value="skis">Skis</option>
        <option value="skins">Skins</option>
        <option value="poles">Poles</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

When you initialize it, use the option `create : true`:

```
$('#select-gear').selectize({
    create: true
});
```

Comment: This seems to solve @Adrian's problem https://github.com/brianreavis/selectize.js/blob/master/docs/plugins.md also helps if custom solution needs to be achieved.

Comment: @jpaljasma Yes, that might help if OP does need to create _categories_, not just tags.

Comment: @Ángela I can't find any demo to how to submit this in a form. It is possible to submit value as string, delimited by comma. "Pitons, Sling, Skins, Poles".

Comment: How are you submitting the form? You mean you are not getting the value server-side? That might need to be another question...

Comment: You can [transform an array into a comma-separated string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list)... but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Selectize supports `<optgroup>`

[image]

Comment: Nice, but I still want to keep function to add my own tags, which are not in the input list.