# How to concat 2 strings separated by a comma in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am running the following, I'd like to have:

> spaceInfo, info

```
      for (y = 0; y < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space.length; y++) {
        var spaceInfo = document.createElement("p");
        spaceInfo.innerHTML = myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space[y];
        jumbo.appendChild(spaceInfo);
      }

      for (g = 0; g < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time.length; g++) {
        var info = document.createElement("p");
        info.innerHTML = myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time[g];
        jumbo.appendChild(info);
      }
```

I tried:

```
jumbo.appendChild(spaceInfo + ", ");
```

Comment: `But that's jQuery not javaScript.` xD

Comment: @jimmyweb ok ok, removed that line.. yet the question remains

Comment: that was funny. anyway I don't understand the problem.

Comment: check this out: [How to add comma between array items?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45546859/6567275)

Comment: i simply need to add a comma in `jumbo.appendChild(spaceInfo);` in order to have the output of spaceInfo with a comma

Comment: You're appending DOM elements to another dom element, this has nothing to do with strings. If you're trying to visually display a comma in between these two elements, try adding a new div that just has a "," as the inner HTML.

Comment: @Dr_Derp that's correct, I did that as I wasn't able to add a comma, yet it's obviously not what I want as it creates 2 <p>

Comment: @Thomas that's actually nice, with css only

Comment: Where do you want the comma? At the top you show it between `spaceInfo` and `info`, not between each `spaceInfo` element.

Comment: ideally in between the two arrays, the above code is wrong as it is appending two <p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That MAY work, however I don't fully understand your code. It's out of context.

```
  for (y = 0; y < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space.length; y++) {
    var spaceInfo = document.createElement("p");
    spaceInfo.innerHTML = myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space[y] + " ,";
    jumbo.appendChild(spaceInfo);
  }

  for (g = 0; g < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time.length; g++) {
    var info = document.createElement("p");
    info.innerHTML = myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time[g] + " ,";
    jumbo.appendChild(info);
  }
```

Comment: ok got it,  `.Space[y] + " ,";` that's where I should be adding the comma, I was adding it in the append child. Will now change the code not to append on the p. Thanks

Comment: will do as soon as it will let me

Comment: bingo, thanks `for (y = 0; y < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space.length && y < myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time.length; y++) {
            var spaceInfo = document.createElement("p");
            spaceInfo.innerHTML = myArrayElement[i].Arg.Space[y] + ", " + myArrayElement[i].Arg.Time[y];
            jumbo.appendChild(spaceInfo);
          }`