# How to reduce code of multiple if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, optimization

I am trying to validate a large contact form. When the user forgets a required input field then I populate the empty variable with default text.

My current solution uses nine `if` statements. Is there a better way to do it with **less code**?

> **html:** `<xehases class="" id="xehases"></xehases>`

```
var onoma = $("#fname").val();
var eponimo = $("#lname").val();
var email = $("#email").val();
var diefthinsi = $("#address").val();
var poli = $("#city").val();
var xora = $("#country").val();
var katigoriaDiafimisis = $("#AdCategory").val();
var plano = $("#plan").val();
var istoselida = $("#website").val();
var epixirisi = $("#company").val();
var minima = $("#message").val();

var missing = '  ';

if (onoma === "") {
  missing += 'Όνομα ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (eponimo === "") {
  missing += 'Επώνυμο ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (email === "") {
  missing += 'email ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (poli === "") {
  missing += 'Πόλη ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (xora === "please choose a category") {
  missing += 'Χώρα ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (plano === "") {
  missing += 'Πλάνο ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (katigoriaDiafimisis === "") {
  missing += 'Κατηγορία Διαφήμισης ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (epixirisi === "") {
  missing += 'Επιχείρηση ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}

if (minima === "") {
  missing += 'Μήνυμα ';
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
} else {
  $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
}
```

Comment: There is one extra `else{//proceed to ajax}` which is not bound to any `if`

Comment: it shouldn't matter if it is an html tag or not. I created it my own just to remember.

Comment: I would also recommend using english in your code for everything (variables, comments...), even if it is just your small hobby project (to get into the habit). If it is work related, then definitely use english, even if you and all your colleagues speak only greek. You never know who will come after you to maintain it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create a dict containing the form fields and the strings displayed when they are missing and iterate over the list. Also, as another response indicated, move setting the missing error message to the end and only do it once; Further, the if/else for that isn't needed if you're going to do the same thing in each case. Write the code similar to this:

```
// key is form input, value is displayed in missing field message
const fieldsDict = {
    "fname": "Όνομα",
    "lname": "eponimo",
    // ...
};

let missing = "";

Object.keys(fieldsDict).forEach((field) => {
    if ($("#" + field).val() === "") {
        missing += fieldsDict[field] + " ";
    }
});

$("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
```

Comment: const fieldsDict is  javascript?

Comment: @Eternal [yes it is](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

Comment: Yeah, I'll add a comment before that.

Comment: so where should I add "name is missing" or "last name missing"

Comment: Change the line that starts with `missing += fieldsDict` to include text beyond just the field name.

Comment: @JaredSohn the key value pair should be reversed like this: `const fieldsDict = { "fname": "Όνομα",..`

Comment: @adiga yes you are correct it wasn't working without reversing these

Comment: can I add a comma if there are more than 1 empty fields? Like `name,lastname` and not if it is only 1 like  `name is missing,`

Comment: I'd suggest appending the missing fields to an array instead of building a string and then doing an `array.join` with a comma at the end (as suggested as an answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list) So set missing to [] instead of "", do missing.push(fieldsDict[field]) within the forEach, and then do missing.join(", ") when setting the output.

Comment: i have a  dropdown where i have to check if the value is "please choose a category" How can i check that for the variable `xora` see my updated question, you'll understand

Comment: change the if statement to this:  `$("#" + field).val() === '' || $("#" + field).val() === 'please choose a category'`

Answer (score 1):

I can see there is some duplication of the code example

```
          $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
```

This can be put only in the last. So over all you just need to build the content of **missing** variable.

```
         if(onoma === "")
             missing +='Όνομα ';
         if(eponimo === "")
             missing+='Επώνυμο ';   
         if(email === "")
            missing+='email ';
         if(poli === "")
            missing+='Πόλη ';
         if(xora === ""){
           missing+='Χώρα ';  
          // and more               
          $("xehases#xehases").html(missing);
```

Comment: @Eternal I have updated my answer with the code , please have a look if I get it right...

Comment: you forgot the else on each if. You have to clear the variable if nothing is empy

Comment: @Eternal The variable is empty to start with, and a list of the missing fields is being created inside it.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this...

```
var fields = ['fname', 'lname', 'email']; // ...and so on
var errField = $('#xehases');

function submit(){
    fields.forEach(function(field){
        var domElem = $('#' + field);
        if (domElem.val() === '') {
            errField.html(errField.text() + ' ' + domElem.attr('err-msg'));
        }
    });
}
```

'err-msg' could be an attribute on input elem used for missing msg.