# Going through unknown number of arrays in a variable and return the values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have some values in a variable that could contain unknown number of arrays. for example,

```
digitalData.product[0] = "123";
digitalData.product[1] ="456";
```

and so on.

How is it possible to go through this arrays and then return the values? So, the desired output would be - 123;456;. Would the below work?

```
function range(start, count) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        count = start;
        start = 0;
    }

    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        foo.push(start + i);
    }
    return digitalData.product.foo;
}
```

I would very much appreciate any help.

Comment: share the complete array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easy way to turn JavaScript array into comma-separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list)

Comment: Don't think this is duplicate of the above as the range of my array is not known beforehand.

Comment: Can you explain more? Where are these unkown number of arrays? I only see one.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the length of the digitalData.product array could be anywhere from 0 to let's say 10000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `slice` to return the subarray you want. Don't worry about count going way beyond the end of the array as `slice` stops at the end of the array. Once you get that subarray, just join the results using or `join(";")`:

```
function range(start, count) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        count = start;
        start = 0;
    }

    return digitalData.product.slice(start, start + count).join(";");
}
```

**Example:**

```js
var digitalData = {
  product: ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee", "fff", "ggg"]
};

function range(start, count) {
    if (arguments.length == 1) {
        count = start;
        start = 0;
    }

    return digitalData.product.slice(start, start + count).join(";");
}

console.log(`range(1, 3):     "${range(1, 3)}"`);
console.log(`range(2):        "${range(2)}"`);
console.log(`range(4, 10000): "${range(4, 10000)}"`);
console.log(`range(1000, 10): "${range(1000, 10)}"`);
```

Comment: Thanks, I quite like this. So, is it going to give me the output as 123;456;789 and so until the array finishes?

Comment: @SyedHaque That's why I asked you in the comment right bellow your question. Do you want the result to be an array (example: `["aaa", "bbb"]`) or a string (example: `"aaa,bbb"`)?

Comment: apologies. I want the results to be a string i.e. "123;456;789"

Comment: @SyedHaque Updated!

Comment: Excellent! Thanks @IbrahimMahrir

Answer (score 0):

if your desired output is like this - 123;456;789;

then you just have to join array with ";".

> digitalData.product.join(";");

it will give you the same output what you want.

Comment: So do you mean I just replace this line - return digitalData.product.foo with return digitalData.product.join(";");

Comment: yes, and remove all other code.
remove that "range" function. 
now its not needed if you are going to use above method.

var output = digitalData.product.join(";");
console.log(output);
you will get result in output variable'

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
digitalData = {};
digitalData ['product'] = ["123", "456"];

function range(arguments) {
    if (arguments.product.length == 1) {
        start = 0;
        count = start+1;
    } else{
        start = 0;
        count = arguments.product.length;
    }

    var foo = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        foo.push(arguments.product[start + i]);
    }
    return foo.toString();
}

console.log(range(digitalData));
```

Comment: I try to make same with your ideal, although the "start" variable always 0, it not need to set!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution but the values could be anything. 123, 456 are just examples.