# separate return variables with commas in javascript and displaying it in JSP

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

In javascript by this code

```
 var cartname+=cartArray[i].name;// cartArray[i].name returns names like 
                                    Orange, Banana, Apple

 document.getElementById("cartname").value= cartname; // sending to home.jsp by id cartname
```

In home.jsp

---

```
    <input type ="text" id="cartname"/> // got output like OrangeBananaApple 
                                            i.e. without commas
```

I tried to separate above with comma by following code:

```
      cartname+=cartArray[i].name;
      var cartname2=[cartname];
    document.getElementById("cartname2").value= cartname2.join(",");
```

Still got no result. How to get output separated with commas like following in home.jsp

```
       Orange, Banana, Apple
```

Comment: Hi I tried with above code but no output is coming, even I am not getting Orange Banana Apple output also

Comment: @Tom can you post the complete code, from where cartArray[i] is coming and is there's anything else you're doing with cartName before assigning to DOM element

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487562/how-to-return-multiple-values-from-javascript-to-jsp?noredirect=1#comment99570062_56487562

Answer (score 1):

You can add `cartArray[i].name` with a trainling space. Then while setting the value of the input `trim` the string use replcae to replace white space with `,`

```js
//' orange apple mango'; // string with white space before adding to value
let cartName6 =' '+cartArray[i].name;
console.log(cartName6.trim().replace(/ /g, ','))
```

Comment: Hi I am getting single output like either Orange or Banana or Apple but not all . 
  cartname+=cartArray[i].name; // += attribute is to be added I think

Comment: where can I add += attribute to display multiple fruit names

Comment: Hi thanks for helping me.. I tried like this   cartname+=[cartArray[i].name];
            
  document.getElementById("cartname").value= cartname.trim().replace(/ /g, ','); 
but did n't work actually, can u pls correct me

Comment: Why `cartname+=[cartArray[i].name]; ` instead of `cartname+=cartArray[i].name; ` ?

Comment: ok I edited my final code 'var cartname=" "; ' cartname+=cartArray[i].name;
            
  document.getElementById("cartname").value= cartname.trim().replace(/ /g, ','); ' but getting same output i.e. OrangeBananaApple

Comment: @Tom i have again edited the answer for ease of your understanding. Please check

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194628/discussion-between-tom-and-brk).

Comment: Hi brk pls come to chat I need little bit of help to write same in javascript

Comment: @Tom chat block in my location

Comment: Hi brk there is no whitespace in output before. My output is like OrangeMangoApple like this. While running ur code here error is coming in output pls see

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example for converting your array to string and joining it with ",".

```
<script>
 var fruits=["Apple","Banana","Orange"];
 document.write(fruits.join(','));
</script>
```

You can apply it on your own code,

```
document.getElementById("cartname").value= cartArray[i].name.join(',');
```

=>output:

> Apple, Banana, Orange.

Comment: my output is var fruits=[AppleBananaMangoOrange] , there is no comma (,) separated . I have to separate with comma thats the question I have asked

Comment: Hey @Tom, Are you able to share whole cartArray so we may able to figure out why your code does not omitted the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Use `map`,

```
cartname=cartArray.map(e => e.name).join(",");
```

Comment: while applying ur code I am not even getting any output

Comment: What is exact value of cartArray[i].name or cartArray[0].name