# collect all the values of all checboxes to pass through ajax

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, each

I want to get all the values of the checkboxes that are checked, in a string that I can pass through ajax.

```
<input value="1" class="customer" type="checkbox">
<input value="2" class="customer" type="checkbox">
<input value="3" class="customer" type="checkbox">
<input value="4" class="customer" type="checkbox">
<input value="5" class="customer" type="checkbox">
```

so if 2 and 5 are checked, I want to create a variable `var checked='2,5'`

```
var checked_arr = [];
$('.customer:checked').each(function(){
    checked_arr.push($(this).val());
});
checked = JSON.stringify(checked_arr);
$.ajax({
    type    : 'POST',
    url     : '//'+base_url+'/ajax/customers.php',
    data    : 'checked='+checked,
    success : function(data) {
    }
});
```

I think I need to json encode it to pass the array through, but I dont even seem to be creating the array properly. I think I am missing something on pushing the values into the array.

Comment: `.class:checked` should be `.customer:checked`.

Comment: oh yes, sorry, but that still didnt help

Comment: That wasn't an answer to the question, it was an unrelated comment. The solution is in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

`JSON.stringify()` will create `["2","5"]`, not `2,5`. You should use

```
var checked = checked_arr.join(',');
```

Or you could just pass the array itself:

```
data: {checked: checked_arr},
```

`$.ajax` will format this so that `$_POST['checked']` will be an array.

Comment: oh ok, what is best for creating a php array on the other side? I dont mind how it looks on the jquery side.

Comment: The second version is best, it happens automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Array.prototype.join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) instead of `JSON.stringify`

```
checked =  checked_arr.join(',');
```

For more details, you can read Wayne's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201733/9071943)