# loop through array of objects and get all object values as a single string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of object

```
 const arr = [
  { id: 1, value: "Apple" },
  { id: 1, value: "Orange" },
  { id: 1, value: "Pine Apple" },
  { id: 1, value: "Banana" },
];
```

I want to loop through this array and get all the fruit names as a single string every fruit will separated with comma. But don't know how to do that. Does anybody help me to do this?

Comment: Answer already here, https://stackoverflow.com/a/65460835/7785337

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?retiredLocale=vi) and [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?retiredLocale=vi) like this

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 1, value: "Apple" },
  { id: 1, value: "Orange" },
  { id: 1, value: "Pine Apple" },
  { id: 1, value: "Banana" },
];
const result = arr.map(({ value }) => value).join(', ')
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const fruitNames = arr.map(fruit => fruit.value).toString();
```