# How to change an array of objects to a string list with commas?

Tags: arrays, angular

I currently have an array in angular that I would like to change the structure of. Example array:

```
0: "Car 1"
1: "Car 2"
2: "Car 3"
3: "Car 4"
4: "Car 5"
5: "Car 6"
```

I would like to convert it to `Car1,Car2,Car3,Car4,Car5` so that I can use the `IndexOf()` function for each comma.

Comment: What is your end goal exactly? Why do you need to use `indexOf` for commas?

Comment: Search after join. And before joining the items, remove the space (if necessary) with f. e. map.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Easy way to turn JavaScript array into comma-separated list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201724/easy-way-to-turn-javascript-array-into-comma-separated-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let yourString = yourArray.map(e => e.replace(/\s/g, "")).join(",")
```

Comment: [`.trim()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_trim_string.asp) only remove the leftmost and rightmost space, but not the space in between words.

Answer (score 1):

```
let array = [ "Car 1" , "Car 2"  ,"Car 3" , "Car 4" , "Car 5"  ];
let newString = array.map(e => e.replace(/\s/g, '')).join(",")
```

Output will be - Car1,Car2,Car3,Car4,Car5